# jasmine spy on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a jQuery function:

```
$.fn.Header = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
        // bla bla
    });
};
```

And somewhere in my code I call it:

```
function initHeader() {
    // some code before

    $('my-header').Header({

    });
}
```

And I have a jasmine test:

```
it('shows header in some cases', function () {
    var Header = spyOn($.fn, 'Header');
    expect(Header).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Header');
});
```

When running a test I get following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('my-header').Header')
    at initHeader
    .....
    Header() method does not exist
```

What is the problem and how I can fix it?

P.S. I have added jQuery to karma.conf.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like a jasmine error as it is thrown from code. Seems it is not able to find your Header method. Check if the js file with $.fn.Header definition is included as well in karma config.

Comment: as @aarjithn pointed out , your reference to the definition is not included